# GWT CkEditor loading issue

Tags: gwt

```
I am using GWT-CKEditor in my application. When I am trying to load it, it gives following Exception..

Caused by: com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException: One or more exceptions caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException.tryCommand(AttachDetachException.java:87)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Panel.doAttachChildren(Panel.java:170)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onAttach(Widget.java:345)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException$1.execute(AttachDetachException.java:34)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException.tryCommand(AttachDetachException.java:74)
    ... 95 more
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): $wnd.CKEDITOR is undefined
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:289)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
    at com.axeiya.gwtckeditor.client.CKEditor.replaceTextArea(CKEditor.java)
    at com.axeiya.gwtckeditor.client.CKEditor.initInstance(CKEditor.java:178)
    at com.axeiya.gwtckeditor.client.CKEditor.onLoad(CKEditor.java:169)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite.onAttach(Composite.java:179)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException$1.execute(AttachDetachException.java:34)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException.tryCommand(AttachDetachException.java:74)
    ... 99 more
```

Comment: It seems something is being missed when initializing CkEditor.Provide the code snippet

Comment: hey it is done. I missed to provide to script for it.

Comment: Its good practice to answer your question and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I forgot to provide script in html file.. this is how we can achieve this. Its working..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/v4workflow/ckeditor/ckeditor.js?t={timestamp}"></script>
```